# Criar uma query dentro de um arquivo de funções na pasta libraries e não no model como sugerido

Tags: codeigniter

Preciso verificar um certo tipo de permissão que está na tabela de permissões no banco de dados MYSQL. 
Nesse caso, vou precisar usar uma função que está dentro da pasta "libraries" num arquivo chamado "functions.php".

O objectivo dessa função é apenas verificar se o usuário tem a acesso a botões  específicos  dentro de uma determinada "view". Se tiver mostra os botões relacionados.

Sendo assim, qual o caminho mais adequado a seguir?

1. Criar um "model" e chamá-lo em minha função que está dentro da pasta "libraries" num arquivo chamado "functions.php".
2. Fazer a consulta diretamente dentro da função que está dentro da pasta "libraries" num arquivo chamado "functions.php".

Confesso que é tentador usar a segunda opção mas não quero ferir o padrão "mvc". Já vi muita gente na internet a criar queries dentro de funções que não pertencem ao model ou controller.

Gostava de saber a opinião de vocês.

Comment: Não sei exatamente como esta o seu código mas tente não violar o principio SRP do SOLID.

Comment: A pergunta é plausível. Pode estar mal expressada, mas entendi perfeitamente a dúvida do user737. A resposta é bem objetiva

Comment: Apesar de não entender *bulhufas* de codeigniter, me parece ser uma pergunta *respondível* sim.

Comment: Quem reescreveu minha pergunta piorou as coisas! Nem eu entendo isso aí que escreveram!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Então, desenvolvo sistemas com o CI faz um bom tempo, e minha resposta seria que depende do que você está fazendo.

A primeira sugestão, o que eu uso, é retornar a privacidade do usuário na hora do login e guarda-la em sessão, como o CI possibilita pelo user data. Faço com com todos os dados que uso constantemente do usuário, como e-mail, login, apelido, idioma e permissão.

```
function mountSessionUser($userData) {
//força o carregamento da instância do CI
$CI = & get_instance();

$CI->session->set_userdata(['user-data' => json_encode($userData)]);
}
```

Depois, se existir:

```
$usuario = $CI->session->userdata('user-data');
```

Quer dizer que o usuário está logado e você terá todos os dados dele que fez no login, sem consultar o banco.

Agora, sobre o ponto principal da pergunta, que é sobre a relação com o banco de dados fora das models. Eu utilizo sim, sem problemas, mas sempre oriento minha equipe da maneira que escolhemos usar no projeto.

Dados coerentes a serem lidos do banco para a renderização de uma página devem estar sempre na model ou já pre carregados, como o exemplo do nome do usuário. Outras funções, porém, que não estão ligadas a dados que serão mostrados ou que executam tarefas paralelas ou comuns a todo o sistema podem, ao meu ver, estar nas libraries sim. Um exemplo disso são as duas bibliotecas que uso para gerenciamento dos usuários.

Dentro da model mantenho as queries responsáveis pela renderização de listagem de usuários, amigos de usuários, e por ai vai. Mas a função de alterar senha, que no caso pode ser feito via site e via API, fica na biblioteca de gerenciamento do usuário, chamada diversas vezes na aplicação, não só no controller de usuário.

Comment: Obrigado Caio. 
Acabei por fazer o seguinte (como eles editaram e suspenderam, eu fiquei sem respostas e resolvi seguir meus instintos): eu mantive a query no model e fiz um chamado dele (o model) para essa função assim: 

function show_btn($class=NULL, $method=NULL){

$this->CI->load->model('admin/auth_m');
return $this->CI->auth_m->show_btn($class, $method);

}

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se realmente entendi a sua pergunta, mas creio que entendi e vou tentar responder.

O ideal é gravar em sessão essa informação tão breve você consiga acessa-la, porem para ter acesso a essa informação você precisaria fazer a consulta e o ideal é sempre fazer isso no Model para não ferir o padrão MVC (como você mesmo colocou).

Eu acredito que você venha conseguir melhores respostas se você nos mostrar parte do código. Seria uma consulta a tabela do próprio banco MySQL ou seria uma consulta ao banco da sua aplicação?

Comment: Obrigado Zignd. Acabei por fazer o seguinte (como eles editaram e suspenderam, eu fiquei sem respostas e resolvi seguir meus instintos): eu mantive a query no model e fiz um chamado dele (o model) para essa função assim: function show_btn($class=NULL, $method=NULL){ $this->CI->load->model('admin/auth_m'); return $this->CI->auth_m->show_btn($class, $method); }

Minha dúvida era somente se poderia criar uma query fora model ou controller ou seja dentro de uma classe específica criada por mim mesmo.